# More than one same apps in /usr/share/applications

Tags: files, directory

There are more duplicated applications in my `/usr/share/applications` directory. How do I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The icons looking the same does not mean they are the same. Some of these will be launchers with different settings. The 3 names "Files" can have different locations they point to.

Nevertheless: these are merely desktop files. So you can remove them if you want. From command line:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
sudo rm {desktop-file-to-remove}
```

---

How to identify the one to remove?

You can search for the file names by looking for the name it shows at the Icon. Example with "Files" from my system (I have 3 there):

```
/usr/share/applications$ grep Files *
nautilus.desktop:Name=Files
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop:Name=Files
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Name=Files
```

---

Use `more nautilus.desktop` to view this desktop file and see if you can find out if it is a duplicate of the other desktop files it listed by comparing the files. You can also do a `diff nautilus.desktop nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`. It will list if there are differences between the 2 files.

---

Instead of removing them you should be moving them to another location. That way you can restore the desktop file if you remove the wrong one.